# How to find with Firebug or any other extension what Javascript code triggers form submission?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, form-submit, firebug

I have a strange bug - shortly after the web page loads, a form is being submitted (form submission is triggered by Javascript code obviously). The problem is that I can't find the piece of code that submits the form. Is it possible to find it using Firebug or any other extension?

Comment: Just search for submit() in ur codebase, put a breakpoint in al possible places (i.e., wherever u call submit() of the form object). hope ur aware of the usage of firebug.

Comment: thanks, but the things is that codebase is huge, so it's not possible

Comment: Well., Your codebase might be huge. But, Your page might be using just few files. So better u just search for "submit()" in firebug itself. That will show all placeholders of submit(). Then put breakpoints in all the places and wait :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem, this can be done by adding

```
form.submit = function(event) {console.trace()}
```

Thus, we redefined submit handler for the form, and instead of being submitted, it will print trace info to the console.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome developer tools, if you click on the 'pause' button when you are not stopped on a breakpoint or anything, I've experienced that it paused on very next script piece its going to execute. May be that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add below script into very top of the <head> element.

```
for (var i= 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
    document.forms[i].onsubmit = function(e){
        console.log(e);
        console.trace();
        alert("wait a minute...");
    };
}
```

That code should intercept all forms submission on the page.

After form submission you will find event object dump and call stack trace in firebug console while alert blocking request.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it won't be caught if form is submitted from javascript, like form.submit()